# XCode wont let me use a Static Library View in my xib files

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, interface-builder

I created a new project of type Static Linked Library.

I have moved the code (previously working in the app) to the library leaving all the xib files in the app.

I have changed the export directory and added the library file from the derived data folder so it gets the compiled version and links to it.

I have added the library to the bundle and have verified it is in the app using iPhone Explorer

I have verified that the xib file recognized the new view type by removing and selecting the custom view type in the custom class field of the identity inspector.

I have changed all of the #import commands to reflect the <> VS "" change and have gotten the app to compile.

however none of the methods of my custom class can be executed. and an NSLog reports that the class is its base counterpart as opposed to the custom derived class.

I am at a loss and have spend a long time converting all the code I have to work in a library. I am hoping someone can help with this.

Comment: Seriously ? nobody can assist with this ? is this unheard of or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this issue, it turns out that Objective C's compiler does not load the categories and custom classes in the libraries by default. There are 2 ways to overcome this.

And here are your options.

1. Create an Activation type method on the category that will be called to "Activate" that Class or Category. This will need to be done before the application loads any nib files. And seems like a bit of a pain in the butt. This was however how I originally overcame this issue.
2. Add linker flags that will tell objective C to load all libraries and attach any and all Categories and Classes within the libraries before executing the application. (this will need to be done, on top of #import(ing) the correct files from their correct locations. I will provide a graphic below. and provide the flags for search purposes

[image]

-ObjC is the first one I added, but -all_load really did the trick.

I hope that others can benefit from this experience.